# How to block all servers connected with a domain name

Tags: windows, networking, ping

How to block all servers of a service? For example, you want to block all of roblox, as roblox has a different server for its website and for its various games, etc.
When I run `ping www.roblox.com`, I get:

> ping www.roblox.com
>   Pinging www.roblox.com [8.42.96.25] with 32 bytes of data:
>   Reply from 8.42.96.25: bytes=32 time=66ms TTL=246
>   Reply from 8.42.96.25: bytes=32 time=68ms TTL=246
>   Reply from 8.42.96.25: bytes=32 time=68ms TTL=246
>   Reply from 8.42.96.25: bytes=32 time=66ms TTL=246
>   Ping statistics for 8.42.96.25:
>       Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
>   Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>       Minimum = 66ms, Maximum = 68ms, Average = 67ms

I get the IP address `69.172.201.47` and `8.42.96.25`, but which one should I block? Which is the server and which is the web server?

#### Edit

When I run `nslookup www.roblox.com`, it gives me:

```
nslookup www.roblox.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.6.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.roblox.com
Address:  8.42.96.30
```

Comment: Instead of `ping`, run `nslookup` to get a list of the IPs.

Comment: Where are you getting `69.172.201.47` from?

Comment: @DavidPostill I get it from `ping roblox.com`

Comment: But its never shown in any of your output? Depending on their DNS configuration you won't be able to just ask them for a list of all their IPs. It's also unclear whenever you're trying to block incoming or outgoing traffic. Depending on the tools that are available and what/how you're trying to block you might be able to just use the DNS name.

Comment: @Seth I did explain it in my question. It is in the first `{}` part.

Comment: No, it is not. Your example only shows `8.42.96.25`. Also notice that your `nslookup` returns yet another one and if I do a lookup I could get you yet another one. It's likely that you really want a DNS name based block rather than a IP block but its still unclear what you're actually looking for and what kind of infrastructure you got in place to implement it. A network with a dedicated DNS server has different options available in comparison to a standalone machine.

Comment: @Seth My mistake for the IP. Also since you live in Germany and I live in the West Coast of the United States, the Roblox IPs are most likely different.

Comment: What is the context of this question? Are you trying to block Roblox for an entire network? Are you trying to disable the online portion of the game while allowing the other parts to function? Is this a home network or a business network? Are you just trying to block the game on a personal computer? For each of these cases the answer will be different, and so without them the question is too broad to answer.

Comment: Further, in order to block all possible addresses of a service you must know all their IPs. Simply looking for the IPs associated with roblox.com is far from enough. roblox.com will be their web presence, but the game clients very likely connect to a different domain or different IPs. Finding these is impossible unless all the domains are published in the documentation for the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open notepad as Administrator:

1. Open Start
2. Type `notepad`
3. Right click and press `Run as Administrator`

Press `File` > `Open`, then navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`.  Click the dropdown so that it shows all file types, then double-click the 'hosts' file (it has no file extension).

Go to the bottom, then type:

```
0.0.0.0 www.roblox.com
```

Save the document, then close.  Access to the domain `www.roblox.com` will be routed to the IP address `0.0.0.0`, which doesn't exist.  Incidentally, this is the method used by Spybot Anti-Beacon, the anti-Windows-10-surveillance tool.

Comment: I found this on [another site](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/block-ip-address-computer-56530.html) and they told me to use the `127.0.0.1` IP.

Comment: Also does it block only the web server at [roblox.com](http://www.roblox.com) or both the web server and the game server.

Comment: @ds_secret this will block any traffic on any protocol, so both of the above.  You can route it to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1 as 0.0.0.0 sends you nowhere and 127.0.0.1 routes to your local machine - technically, this is less robust.  You can do either, but for "reasons" I recommend 0.0.0.0

Comment: What are those "reasons"?

Comment: @ds_secret if you had a web server running on your local machine with no binding to a specific domain name or IP, entering the address would route you to that web server.  The same applies for any other type of protocol running on any port.  I assume that this isn't the desired outcome so using 0.0.0.0 just makes sure that *nothing* can come through.

Comment: It's the easiest approach but does have a caveat. If you do have other related domain names like `robolox.com` (missing the `www.`) or `gameserver.robolox.com` those won't be blocked unless you list each DNS name individually.

Comment: @Seth for the scenario given by the OP, it works...  Also, does `*.example.com` work?

Comment: As far as I can tell you can't use wildcards and yes, for that single DNS name it works. Even if you add more but depending on what she/he knows about how their services operate (multiple game servers) it might be necessary to add more DNS names. So I just wanted to point it out.